# Under load PHP communications with MySQL (seperate box) breaks

Tags: php, mysql, connection, loading

Our website today received an increase in users (about double our normal load) and our system has started to slow down. Our MySQL sits on it's own physical box, and we've started receiving these errors in our logs;

`[Mon Jul 18 15:30:07 2011] [error] [client 2.221.255.55] PHP Warning:  mysql_select_db() [<a href='function.mysql-select-db'>function.mysql-select-db</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/livesite/_util.inc on line 301, referer:`

The MySQL box is fine, and responds quite happily to our development server, but our live server, as of this load increase, is seeing this error message.

Does anybody know why PHP would just stop communication with MySQL on another box?

Comment: I would imagine this would have to do with the maximum number of outbound connections configured in your HTTP server. How many connections are you talking about here?

Comment: About 300 per second according to the Apache charts

Comment: Are you using an implicit mysql_connect()? If you've explicitly coded a mysql_connect() then you've got a problem with the number of connections each script is opening.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection limit is likely too low.  Usually you get a different error, but I wouldn't be surprised if this were the problem:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

I suspect that line 301 is calling some function, such as `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which explains the error.  There is probably a different error on connect, such as "too many connections", but that won't be in your logs if your connect line has an `@` in front of it.

Comment: It may also be beneficial to log in to the MySQL server using SUPER and check the ShowProcessList as explained in the article that Brad linked.

Comment: We've connected our development server to the MySQL box and it runs without an issue. So we think we can rule the MySQL box out

Comment: @Dom, these things can crop up and vanish quickly.  On a heavily loaded server, there may be a very good chance you can get logged in 1 millisecond, and not the next.  Keep your evidence in mind, but don't rule out the possibility that you need to increase your connection limit.  Simply checking the process list will verify this issue.

Comment: We checked the process list and it's currently sitting  at 14 (earlier it was 18-20).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shuold look at your PHP INI file for mysqli.max_persistent and the like ?
Maybe your logic connects without disconnecting - fast enough ?

Comment: OP isn't using mysqli, though... but yes, it's most likely a max_connections-type limit.

Comment: We are using mysql instead of mysqli - but mysql.max_links is set to -1 (which according to the config means no limit)